# Linq simple query improvement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm a beginner in Linq queries and I'm wondering if my query can be improved one way ore another:

```
long vehid = json.VehicleId.Value;
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(json.date.Value);

var Alerts = (from t2 in entities.Alerts.AsNoTracking()
              where 
                 t2.GeneratedTimeLocal.Year == date.Year
              && t2.GeneratedTimeLocal.Month == date.Month
              && t2.GeneratedTimeLocal.Day == date.Day
              && (t2.AlertType == 2 || t2.AlertType == 3)
              && t2.vId == vid
              select new
              {
                  GeneratedTimeLocal = t2.GeneratedTimeLocal,
                  OptionalText = t2.OptionalText
              });

return Alerts;
```

The problem is that the Alerts datatable has a huge amount of data in it that increases day by day and right now it's kind of slow.
The `GeneratedTimeLocal` field from Alerts datatable is type datetimeoffset(7).
Is there a way to improve this query?

Comment: You say `DataTable`, but I assume you mean it's an SQL database? If you run the equivalent query in SQL, is it very fast?

Comment: Your problem is not in LINQ, it is in the DB. Your LINQ query is translated into SQL and you have to improve that one (e.g. with an index) to improve performance.

Comment: One option is to check a date range instead of just the year, month, day.  Basically if you want 2017-12-13 then you want the range of 2017-12-13 00:00:00.000 to 2017-12-13 23:59:59.999.  Then with indexing on your date column that should result in a faster query versus hitting each row to pull out the year, month, and date.  And of course indexing on the other columns in your filter will help as well.  Consider capturing the resulting query and running it through a SQL analyzer for your DB to get hints about indexes.

Comment: Please add a tag for your linq provider. Is this Entity Framework?

Comment: @nvoigt Yes, you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a date range to improve the query. Then check the query execution plan and based on that decide if you need a new index or change existing indexes.

```
long vehid = json.VehicleId.Value;
DateTime dateFrom = DateTime.Parse(json.date.Value).Date; // date with no time
DateTime dateTo = dateFrom.AddDays(1); // add one day to create the date range

var Alerts = (from t2 in entities.Alerts.AsNoTracking()
              where 
                 t2.GeneratedTimeLocal >= dateFrom 
              && t2.GeneratedTimeLocal <= dateTo
              && (t2.AlertType == 2 || t2.AlertType == 3)
              && t2.vId == vid
              select new
              {
                  GeneratedTimeLocal = t2.GeneratedTimeLocal,
                  OptionalText = t2.OptionalText
              });

return Alerts;
```

On the other hand, remember that this query won't be executed until you do a ToList(), for example.

Try this index:

CREATE INDEX IX_Alert_GeneratedTimeLocal_vId_AlertType_with_include ON Alert(GeneratedTimeLocal, vId, AlertType) INCLUDE(OptionalText)

I'm assuming you're using SQL Server. You could also try a filtered index if the table is huge. Check out this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :)